# How to run Java Applet program from windows cmd?

Tags: java, cmd, applet

I have a Java program below which should ask the user to input a number in the applet window and process further on the basis of given. But the problem is that i am not able to run this java code through cmd
i know my main method is empty but i dont know what to put in it?

CODE

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class Table extends Applet {
    private Label msg;
    TextField number;

    public void init()
    {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Label heading = new Label("Multiplication Table");
        number = new TextField(10);
        Button button = new Button("  Press  ");
        msg = new Label("");
        add(heading);
        add(number);
        add(button);
        add(msg);
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    }
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String str=" ";
            int n = Integer.parseInt(number.getText());
            if(n%2==0 && n>=11 && n<=90)
            {
                for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
                    str = str+ n*i+" ";
                }   
            }
            else {
                str = "Try Again! Number must be even and between 11-90";
            }
            msg.setText(str);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { }
}
```

Comment: Can you rewrite this code using modern technologies? `Applet` hasn't been used much for 20 years and the tools to support them have been deprecated and are hard to find.

Comment: *But the problem is that i am not able to run this java code* Correct. Applets are removed entirely as of Java 11, the browser plugin has not worked for at least five years. In short, you will not be able to run this Java code without a time machine.

Comment: i know guys but i am in india, and its my college project so cant change the method..

Comment: Step One: Build a flux capacitor. Step Two: Plutonium! Step Three: Eighty-eight miles per hour.